# Postgresql Inheritance : Parent can be in two Child and c

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

In postgres sql inheritance:

Parent: Person
Child : Professor
Child : Student

Student can be a Professor
How to manage insert with solo parent ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean multiple inheritance ?